# How to route to another page in blazor wasm after authendication state changed(logged in)by getting the event callback from AuthendicationState

Tags: asp.net-core, blazor, blazor-webassembly

i'm working on a Blazor wasm application, it was Authendicated by Oauth authendication(MSAL azure ADD) whenever i tried to login it opens a chrome windows popup to get the user data from MSAL. After getting the user data the AuthendicatioState was changed. i'm using that AuthendicationState change event callback to invoke a method that i used to redirect the user to home page.

AuthendicationStateChanged Eventcallback to invoke a method in a razor page. in that method
i tried <NavigationManager.NavigateTo("Home");> this line of code to redirect the user.
but it's not working, Also the same code
<NavigationManager.NavigateTo("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=szvt1vD0Uug&list=RDszvt1vD0Uug&start_radio=1");> with another link it works.

Comment: Please format your code in the answer, You can try this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/920983/blazor-azure-b2c-redirect-to-certain-page-based-on)